# How to know if system is restoring from savedInstanceState in viewModel

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

Using Architecture Component, When onCreate, I use the `ViewModel` to fetch the data.

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
fun onCreate() {
    fetchData()
}
```

However, if it is being restored from `savedInstanceState`, I would like to avoid calling `fetchData`. How could I do so?

i.e. using the old way, I could do below.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    if (savedinstanceState == null) {
        fetch()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute the `fetchData()`call inside the `ViewModel` constructor.